# Apply Slick filter depending on condition

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following Slick function that has a filter `(d.sk < sk)`:

```
   def func1(sk: Int) = {
      val date2 = TableQuery[DatesDB] 
      val action = date2.filter( d => (d.sk < sk)).result
      val future = db.run(action.asTry)
      future.map {
        case Success(s) => 
          if (s.length > 0)
            Some(s(0))
          else
            None
        case Failure(e) => throw new Exception("Failure")
      }
   }
```

What I need is to add a feature to this function that depending on a condition X the filter should be either the existent one or `(d.sk <= sk)`. Since filters are not variables I don't know how to achieve this, and I prefer not to rewrite the filters or actions. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/cvogt/9193220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyrille's link seems to be about a bit different case but that approach might be extended to cover your case as well. Still if this is just one place, what's wrong with good old `if`:

```
val date2 = TableQuery[DatesDB] 
val query = if (condition) date2.filter(d => (d.sk < sk)) else date2.filter(d => (d.sk <= sk))
val action = query.result
```

Another idea

```
val date2 = TableQuery[DatesDB] 
val action = date2.filter(d => ((LiteralColumn(condition) && (d.sk < sk)) || (LiteralColumn(!condition) && (d.sk <= sk))).result
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that usually my conditions are large, not simple as in my example, so it would be harder to maintain. I was trying to avoid duplicating the filter and have one with part of it variable depending on the condition.

Comment: @ps0604, probably it would be easier to answer if you provided a more realistic example. Currently I don't understand how you filtering rules change depending on condition. Still, take a look at my "another idea"

Comment: Are you sure your "Another idea" works? I tried to use a Boolean variable called `condition` in the filter and I get multiple errors.

Comment: @ps0604, I was not sure that this idea is what you want so I didn't put much effort. But if it is, please see update: you just have to wrap boolean into a `LiteralColumn` to make it `Rep`.